# External CSS ID selector not working

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, styles, external

Hey guys I have an external CSS and HTML file, I am currently trying to link the two, more specifically I am trying to link the ids that are  `titleImage` `titleLink` and `webpageTitle`. Unfortunately the CSS for does not seem to register. I have tried switching the position of the type and the id such as instead of this, `#titleImage img` that did not work. Is it an issue with me having multiple external CSS references? Also this is not all the code there is more to each but the ones listed below are the parts that I focus on the most. I have also tried removing the `a`, `img`, `h1`

So could someone explain why `titleImage` `titleLink` and `webpageTitle` styles are not registering on my localhost?

UPCDATE: I have made change to reflect everyone's comments below and the site is still not updating with the new css as listed in the code below in style.css

style.css

```
div#titleImage {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0em;
    }
a#titleLink { text-decoration: none}

h1#webpageTitle {
    position:relative;
   }
```

HTML file

```
 <head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alef:400,700|Roboto+Slab'  rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->

    <link href="/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

<body>
    <section class="container">
        <header class="row" id="header">
        <!-- Begin grid -->
            <div class="col-sm-9"><!--Top of the page-->
                <a href="/" id="titleLink" style="color:#000000"><h1 id="webpageTitle">McMaster SEClub</h1></a>
            <div id="titleImage"><img src="/img/logo.gif" width=150 height=110></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `titleImage` ID is for the `<div>` surrounding the image, not the image itself. At the moment, you are trying to find an element with a `#titleImage` selector inside an image tag.

For the `titleLink`, the ID is the element, so you can do this instead:

```
a#titleLink { ... }
```

However, you'd typically only have **one** ID on a page, so you could just target the title link by doing this:

```
#titleLink { ... }
```

The webpage title should be working as intended. However, I'd still recommend just using the ID. An element with relative positioning doesn't really appear different unless you've given it some style declarations:

```
#webpageTitle {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried editing the div and also removing the `a` and the `h1`, yet still no avail. I also tried removing everything and just leaving the identifiers it still does not want to change

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space in the selector.

`img #titleImage` means: any element with id `titleImage` and an `<img>` element as ancestor
`img#titleImage` means: an `<img>` element with id `titleImage`. That's what you want.

Comment: I have tried removingthe space nothing happens still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the space between the tag type and the id.  So and make the rules:

```
img#titleImage {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0em;
}

a#titleLink { text-decoration: none}

h1#webpageTitle {
    position:relative;
}
```

What you have is saying "the element with an ID titleImage that id a child of an image tag, etc.

Since you are using IDs, its not necessary to even include the tag type (a, img) in front of the ids.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser's cache and done a hard refresh to make sure you're not just seeing old, cached styles?

Comment: I have I changed code I know that works, and it changes, odd for this part the site does not seem to change

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any spaces in front of id so the code should be:

```
img#titleImage {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0em;
    }
a#titleLink { text-decoration: none}

h1#webpageTitle {
    position:relative;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all your capital letters, it doesn't work with capitals.

So instead of title**L**ink, and title**I**mage, write title**l**ink and title**i**mage.

That should fix it, it fixed it for me.